# How can I make a standard notation for all beatbox sounds?

Tags: notation, beatbox

I'm working on a beatbox site, and I can use the old school notation for beatbox, like "K" for KSnare, "B" for kick, and "Peh" for peh snare.

##### [This is my website](https://www.beatboxer.ir/technical/cj/)

but the old system has a limitation and I want to cover all sounds in patterns.

I want to create a notation system for beatbox sounds, similar to music notation.

#### What I've tried

In beatboxing, sounds can be categorized as follows:

- Snare: The snare sound can be represented by the letter "S" or "SN."
- Whistle: The whistle sound can be denoted using the symbol "W."
- Bass: The bass sound can be represented by the letter "B."
- Scratch: The scratch sound can be denoted using the symbol "SC."
- Rolls: The rolls sound can be denoted using the symbol "R"

In addition, if you want to indicate whether a sound is produced through inward or outward breaths, you can use the symbols "<" for inward and ">" for outward. Here's an example:

- Inward Teeth Whistle: "< Teeth W"
- Outward Teeth Whistle: "> Teeth W"

Tongue: The sounds produced using the tongue can be represented by the letter "T."

Lips: Sounds involving the lips can be represented by the letter "L."

Teeth: Sounds produced using the teeth can be represented by the letters "TH" (for "Teeth").

Throat: Sounds produced in the throat can be represented by the letters "THR" (for "Throat").

Revised notation:

Tongue Whistle: "< T W"

Lip Bass: "L B"

Teeth Snare: "TH S"

Throat Whistle: "THR W"

---

#### Second Solution

But I think Short Names sometimes are misleading so I came up with emojis

Tongue Whistle: ⬅️

This notation represents a whistle sound produced by the tongue. The symbol ⬅️ indicates an inward breath, followed by the emoji  representing the use of the tongue, and finally, the emoji  representing the whistle sound.

Snore Bass: (or )  (Representing the sound of a pig/snore combined with a bass sound)

Outward Click Roll: ➡️️ (Representing an outward click roll)

Inward Click Roll: ⬅️️ (Representing an inward click roll)

Duck Sound:  (Representing a sound similar to a duck)

Liquid Bass:  (Representing a liquid-like bass sound)

Alien Bass:  (Representing an alien-inspired bass sound)

Evil Bass:  (Representing an evil or sinister bass sound)

Zombie Click Roll: ️ (Representing a click roll with a zombie-like quality)

Alien Click Roll: ️ (Representing a click roll with an alien-like quality)

Comment: "How can I make a standard notation" ... Devise a notation and convince everyone else to use it. As beatboxing at its core attempts to emulate a kit you might extend regular kit notation.

Comment: @Lazy that was my thought as well, though I suspect that adding a phonetic component might help, so maybe writing _tss_ and _tsh_ as "lyrics" for various cymbals and that sort of thing.  The problem with this approach is that it would only work for some sounds, so it would introduce some inconsistency.

Comment: @phoog When I was collecting patterns, I noticed that every person uses different phonetics. For example, for the "Lip Roll" sound, someone wrote "Brrrrr." However, without sound, it becomes challenging to understand. That's why I believe we need a standard notation system.

Comment: That is indeed another limitation of phonetics.  You could use the international phonetic alphabet, which would specify ʙ̥ʙ̥ʙ̥ or ʙʙʙ depending on whether the trill is voiced, but these symbols would probably reduce the learning curve only slightly.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beatboxing#Notation _Standard Beatbox Notation SBN_ for anyone else who thought "standard notation" meant staff notation.

Comment: There isn't even a complete 'standard' for standard drum music, so seems it's up to you, and your colleagues to come up with one which, over time, may become 'standard'.

Comment: I'm not finding the central question here. As I understand it, you found the abbreviations unwieldy and propose emojis. What's the question?

Comment: Sounds like what you suggested is like using coloured noteheads instead of conventional percussion notation. But are you going to use a standard stave? How will you actually notate __rhythms__?

Comment: Obligatory [xkcd](https://xkcd.com/927/).

Comment: @MichaelCurtis As I said classic notation is good for basic patterns "ts" is for Hi-hat but there is no rule to cover all sounds like Liproll , vortex whistle , pash laser and etc...

Comment: @SeyedMortezaKamali, I wasn't responding to your question, just adding a note for other unfamiliar with SBN.